# scrollPositionRestoration not working in spartacus-storefront

Tags: angular-router, spartacus-storefront

My requirement is that on route change, the user should always navigate to the top of the page. So, I tried applying `scrollPositionRestoration: 'top'` configuration in `AppRoutingModule` as per the new application structure in 3.2.0, but it is not working.

I have also tried `scrollOffset: [0, 0]`, property. But that, too, is not working.

I have also tried doing the below as per [Spartacus documentation](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/technical-changes-version-3/#default-router-options-changed), but it is also not working.

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: ROUTER_CONFIGURATION,
    useValue: {
      scrollPositionRestoration: 'top',
    },
  },
];
```

Can anyone help me solving this?

Answer (score 1):

Since 3.2.x, Spartacus does not offer the RouterModule mechanism from angular/router due to the new app structure. Unless, you have opted for creating Spartacus with schematics on a shellapp which imports the `AppRoutingModule` in the app.module by default, then you would have been able to use the snippet that you have provided. Since it does not work, I am assuming, you did not create an AppRoutingModule and imported it in your AppModule, therefore not having the angular's router scroll mechanism in place. Going from the documentation you provided on 3.0, it did not say that you needed to create your own AppRoutingModule, which had been properly updated in our documentation when 4.0 [docs](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/updating-to-version-4/#migrating-to-the-reference-app-structure) was released

---

For 4.2.0, we are releasing a custom mechanism for scroll position restoration, where you have control over ignoring routes and query strings to not go back to the top of the page. You would have a functional scroll positioning due to Spartacus having its data loaded asynchronously, whereas it did not work with the out of the box Router's scroll position restoration.

Instead of creating your own `AppRoutingModule`, you can import the `AppRoutingModule` from `@spartacus/storefront`. The documentation for it will be released once 4.2 is released.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `scrollPositionRestoration: 'top'` in `app-routing.module.ts`?

This is an example of the Out of the box Spartacus(3.2.1) of `app-routing.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([], {
      anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
      relativeLinkResolution: 'corrected',
      initialNavigation: 'enabled',
      scrollPositionRestoration: 'top',
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: Tried that also. But not working. I even added scrollOffset: [0, 0],, but not working.